# Spliting ls results in python to only show first result

Tags: python

After using glob to obtain the `ls` results that have `.log` files, I now need to only take the first result of the list.

```
l=glob.glob('*.log*')

l=radius.log.2019-04-03_17', 'radius.log.2019-04-03_12', 'radius.log.2019-04-02_01', 'radius.log.2019-04-02_06', 'radius.log.2019-04-01_09', 'radius.log.2019-04-02_11
```

I want to create new variable `x` that will be `radius.log.2019-04-03_17`
so that I can use the file name in later portions of the code

Comment: `l` is a list, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `glob.glob('*.log*')` command will return a list. I believe `l` here is a list, although your code shows something else.

If you select only the first element using `l[0]`, you'll get the first element. If you want to store that in a variable you could do something like

```
import glob
l = glob.glob('*.log*')
x = l[0]
```